# How can I create baseline alert or anomality detection with Newrelic and prometheus metrics?

Tags: prometheus, alert, newrelic, nrql

I am using Newrelic with Prometheus counter metric. I am trying to create alert that will fire when average of the current week is less than the average of last week. The documentation has some information about baseline alerts, but it seems outdated and the described links are not in the UI. This looks like a very common scenario, so I wander if there is out of the box solution for it.

I tried so use anomaly detection feature - the metric data is not available for this feature.

I tried to create condition with NRQL "COMPARE WITH" - it is not supported in conditions.

Comment: Can you use promql to compare values on Prometheus' side, and pass result to Newrelic? (I'm not familiar with Newrelic, just trying to clarify matter)

Comment: Promethus is used here only as a way to report the raw metric in a known format. all the logic is in Newrelic

Answer (score 2):

As you have noticed, "COMPARE WITH" queries are not supported in NRQL Alerting, so you could write an API Synthetic to execute the NRQL against the GraphQL endpoint. You can then analyze the result and fail the Synthetic if it is outside of your threshold and fire an alert.

See a very good explanation about that in [this New Relic topic](https://forum.newrelic.com/s/hubtopic/aAX8W0000008bHMWAY/relic-solution-alerting-on-compare-with-queries-using-synthetics-api-test-moni).

Comment: I think I  noticed you wrote somthing about baseline alerts and remvoed it, am I right? if so, how can I use baseline alert for this?

Comment: Uhm... no, I did not write anything and then removed it.